# How to subtotal one column and keep total in another column to get variances between the 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do reconciliation between Sum of three columns. They have the same AccountNbr(s). Left column has a number that is one amount, and the other two columns have matching/not matching broken down amounts in few lines. The first table creates duplicate account numbers and duplicate $ amounts.

Example:

```
T1_A, T1_Value, T2_A, T2_Value, T3_A, T3_Value
```

```
16     $800.    16.   300.      16.   500
16.     800.    16.   100.      16.   800
16.     800.    16.   (1000).   16.   200
16.     800.    16.   200.      16.   (300)
```

As you may see, the value for T2 is $800 but the T1_Value creates extra rows, which makes incorrect variance between the two columns. The variance is $0 between T1_V1 and T2_V2. There is a variance (200) between T1_Value and T3_Value, but I get variances line-by-line.

I need to subtotal T2_Value, T3_Value by T2_A, T3_A correspondingly. And only this subtotal will comparing to account 16 and variances calculated.
I tried Sum(Distinct... in different columns— but get still lots of duplicate lines as “padding”. 
The desired result must have only one line for T1_A and subtotal for corresponding T2_V, T3_V. If there are equal rows for each accounts in T2, T3, then T1 can have the same number of rows.

Comment: If you could post your expected output for the sample data it would make it a lot easier to understand the problem. You don't use consistent naming which doesn't help (what is `T2_V2`?), and it seems the value for `T1_Value` is $800, not the value for `T2`, and nowhere can I see a variance of `0` between `T1_Value` and `T2_Value` or of `200` between `T1_Value` and `T3_Value`

Comment: Try to tabulate your own data, and show us some expected data that you want and what you have tried for it.